# Is it safe to remove a script file from within that script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, executable, rm

Imagine I have a script `foo`. It should be run once when the user logs in and isn't needed after a successful run.

My question: Is it safe to remove the script file from within the script?

E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

# do something
...

# if successful
rm /path/to/foo
exit 0
```

Comment: Not entirely unrelated, you could use `#!/bin/bash -e` to ensure that the script file is removed only if nothing goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is safe. If you want to know, why, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handler-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-de

Comment: @jofel Sounds good, I suggest you make this an answer. :-)

Comment: If in doubt you can replace the last two lines with `exec rm /path/to/foo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It it safe to remove the shell file while running it,
since file handlers are not affected by (re)moving the corresponding file.

For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handler-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-de).

Comment: Just be aware that it might not work, depending on your system (ie the `rm <it-self>` will not succeed on HP-Ux.

Comment: @Ouki, why? Wouldn't that violate POSIX?

Comment: @maxschlepzig POSIX allows the deletion of the last link to an executable that is currently being executed to fail: [`unlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html) may fail with `ETXTBUSY`. (Oddly, “pure procedure” and “shared text” aren't defined in the spec; AFAIK they mean a component of an executable program: the executable itself or a library it uses). All major unices other than HP-UX allow executables to be renamed and unlinked.

Comment: @Ouki That should be easy to get around by simply ending the script with `exec rm /path/to/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I was always nervous about this so I did:

```
(sleep 5; rm /path/to/shell/script) &
exit 0
```

Alternately you can chain to a temporary script:

```
echo >/tmp/rmme rm /path/to/shell/script
. /tmp/rmme
```

Comment: In both of your suggested approaches there will still be a shell process which has not finished executing the script by the time it is deleted.

Comment: What you want to do is `exec rm /path/to/shell/script`